# map and zip Tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

Im trying to understand Labels in trees but i cant understand. This is my Datentyp for Tree:

```
data Tree = Node (Label -> Label) Label [Tree]  
type Label = Int
```

I cant understand really , what is the difference between (Label -> Label) and Label ? 
And how can i get correct results from these functions ?

```
    tcm :: (Label -> Bool) -> (Label -> Label) -> Tree -> Tree  
    tzp :: (Label -> Label -> Label) -> Tree -> Tree -> Tree
    tmax :: Label -> Tree -> (Label -> Label)
```

Heres the example trees and similar example with different datentyp for tree and similar functions:

```
t1 = Null
t2 = Tree 2 (Tree 3 Null Null) (Tree 5 Null Null)
t3 = Tree 2 (Tree 3 (Tree 5 Null Null) Null) (Tree 7 Null Null)

data Tree = Null | Tree Label Tree Tree deriving (Eq,Show)
type Label = Integer
```

But in my example tree isnt null or what ?

```
tcm :: (Label -> Label) -> Tree -> Tree
tzp :: (Label -> Label -> Label) -> Tree -> Tree -> Tree

tcm (+1) t1 == Null
tcm (+1) t2 == Tree 3 (Tree 4 Null Null) (Tree 6 Null Null)
tcm (+1) t3 == Tree 3 (Tree 4 (Tree 6 Null Null) Null) (Tree 8 Null Null)

tzp (+) t1 t2 == Null
tzp (+) t2 t3 == Tree 4 (Tree 6 Null Null) (Tree 12 Null Null)
```

Can somebody help me with these functions and tree ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between (Label -> Label) and Label on its own is that the former is a function that, given a Label, produces a new Label.

As for your next question: In the first Tree datatype, a tree can indeed not be Null since your datatype definition doesn't allow for that.

Other than that, you've tagged your question with the binary-tree tag, but the datatype you want to have clarified isn't one for a binary tree since lists can vary in length.